# pycharm run command not escaping properly

Tags: python, json, pycharm, airflow

I'm trying to run airflow in docker via pycharm. Everything works fine when I run unit tests. When I try to do a cli command, though, it seems to be interpreting my arguments... strangely.

Here is what I pass to airflow at the command line via pycharm:

```
trigger_dag etl_pipeline --conf '{"client":"popsicle"}'
```

The script path refers to airflow itself, so this should be equivalent to calling:

```
airflow <above command>
```

When airflow loads up it throws the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/opt/project/venv/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 199, in trigger_dag
    execution_date=args.exec_date)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/client/local_client.py", line 27, in trigger_dag
    execution_date=execution_date)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 49, in trigger_dag
    run_conf = json.loads(conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

When I set a debugger at the point which is breaking, I see that the string looks like this:

```
s = {str} '\\'{client:quest_providence_health_services_2018_07_31}\\''
```

Note that the above is how pycharm renders variables. Returning `s` would return:

```
'\\'{client:quest_providence_health_services_2018_07_31}\\''
```

I'm pretty sure there are too many quotes there, but it isn't clear to me why there are two sets of single quotes when I am only supplying one at the command line. I've tried without the quotes at all, and it just gives me a different parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes needed escaping:

```
trigger_dag etl_pipeline --conf {\"client\":\"popsicle\"}
```